# How to install a single pole humidity sensor on a 2 way switch setup

Tags: electrical

Greetings everyone,

My bathroom fan is controlled by two switches, so wanted to install a humidity sensor on one of them.. but I cannot find a two way switch humidity sensor anywhere...  Could someone please advice me how I can then install this single pole humidity switch to this two way installation?

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Steven

Comment: Do you mean there are switches at 2 locations in the bathroom?  If so that would be 3-way, not 2-way.  If this is what you mean you need to re-wire the circuit instead to 2 single pole switch in parallel so that either switch being "on" will run the fan.  A traditional 3-way circuit in this case doesn't make sense, because depending on the switch position at the other end, the condition "rising humidity" might turn the fan off instead of on.

Comment: How do you want it to work? Do you want two switches and a humidity sensor, or one switch and a humidity sensor? Do you want the switch or switches to turn the fan on even if the sensor doesn't see a humid condition? Or do you want the switch or switches to turn the fan off even if the sensor does see a humid condition?

Comment: @Tyson in other English speaking parts of the world, they are called 2-way switches - because they are located at 2 locations and each switch has 2 active positions ("ways"). It baffles me why they're call 3-way switches in North America.

Comment: Yes -- do you want the switches taken together to serve as an override-ON or an override-OFF for the sensor, or to have a setup where it's possible to override the sensor in both directions?  Or are you replacing one switch with the sensor, and if so, do you want override behavior in either or both directions?

Comment: Also, just where are you in this world? There are all sorts of fancy tricks that can be pulled with relays and such, but it does me no good to suggest parts if they're set up for the wrong voltage or such!

Answer (score 1):

That's a common problem - integrating the functionality of a smart device with a multi-way switch.   This is often confusion over what the desired behavior is; often confusing electronics with a butler.  Consider.

- the other switch is in the downward position.  What do you want the smart device to do?
- the other switch is in the **upward** position.  What do you want the smart device to do?
- the smart device has turned the fan on, and you throw the other switch.  What do you want to happen?
- the smart device has turned the fan OFF, and you throw the other switch.  What do you want to happen?
- if you manually turn it on, should it continue running forever?
- if you manually turn it off, obviously the smart device shouldn't immediately turn it back on.  Ok, so when should it go back to automatic operation?

See, it gets very messy very quickly.   Of course there are obvious answers that make sense to a butler, but how do you make electronics do that?   It's not that easy.  You are better off to choose one control method and stick with it.